# Illegal start of type for a for loop?

Tags: java

Why am I getting the error :java:16: error: illegal start of type

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
```

I have checked old labs and this is the correct usage of it I thought.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class Lab3Panel extends JPanel {

    Lab3Panel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    }

    Lab3Label label[] = new Lab3Label[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        label[i] = new Lab3Label();
        add(label[i]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for loop needs to be in a method, a constructor, or at a bare minimum, between a pair of `{}` brackets.  But probably a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop code is perfectly legal, but it needs to be inside a method for it to actually be interpreted as code and run. Currently its just sitting inside the class declaration along with the line before it, so the poor compiler has no idea what you want to do with that code or when you want it to run. :D

Answer (score 2):

As many already pointed out you need to run the loop from a method. Here is an example:

```
Class Lab3Panel extends JPanel{

Lab3Panel () {

    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
}


Lab3Label[] label = new Lab3Label[9];

newlabels();

public void newlabels()
{

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

    label[i] = new Lab3Label();
    add(label[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be within a method in the Class. Also the array should be declared like this:

`Lab3Label[] label = new Lab3Label[9];`

Comment: I am trying to make an array of the object Lab3Label is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the square brackets need to be next to the Object type, not the variable name.