# Error: Illegal Start Of type: for loop

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my code:
I have checked my curly braces.they all have their pairs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deck
{
    final int SUITS = 4;
    final int RANKS = 13;
    //ARRAY
    double[][]card=new double[SUITS][RANKS];
    for (int suits=0; suits<SUITS; suits++)
    {
        for(int ranks=0; ranks<RANKS; ranks++)
        {
            cards[suits][ranks]=new Card(suit,rank);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> illegal start of type for (int suits=0; suits<SUITS; suits++)
> ```

Comment: put your code in some method

Comment: I cant put it in the main method.what kind of method can i put my code in?

Comment: If this code is supposed to initialize a `Deck` instance, you should put it in a constructor.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691551/for-loop-gets-error-illegal-start-of-type?lq=1
and this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169673/ilegal-start-of-type-for-a-for-loop

Comment: you need to write method for loop you cannot use a loop or any statement directly in class or write a block and put your code inside the block or method

Comment: next step is to fix this line: `cards[suits][ranks]=new Card(suit,rank);`

Comment: that's what I am struggling with right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your code either in a `method`, `constructor` or an `initializer block` for it to execute.

Method -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deck
{

    final int SUITS = 4;
    final int RANKS = 13;

    public void someMethod() {
        //ARRAY
        double[][]card = new double[SUITS][RANKS];
        for (int suits=0; suits<SUITS; suits++)
        {
            for(int ranks=0; ranks<RANKS; ranks++)
            {
                cards[suits][suits] = new Card();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Constructor -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deck
{

    final int SUITS = 4;
    final int RANKS = 13;

    public Deck() {
        //ARRAY
        double[][]card = new double[SUITS][RANKS];
        for (int suits=0; suits<SUITS; suits++)
        {
            for(int ranks=0; ranks<RANKS; ranks++)
            {
                cards[suits][suits] = new Card();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initializer Block -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deck
{

    final int SUITS = 4;
    final int RANKS = 13;

    {
        //ARRAY
        double[][]card = new double[SUITS][RANKS];
        for (int suits=0; suits<SUITS; suits++)
        {
            for(int ranks=0; ranks<RANKS; ranks++)
            {
                cards[suits][suits] = new Card();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a static block, it's instance initializer in you second example. If it was static, then it should begin with "static" keyword: static { ... }

Comment: This part of the code is kinda weird `cards[suits][suits] = new Card();`

Comment: card[suits][ranks]=new Card(suits,ranks);
I am still working on it..not sure if its right though..

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal yes, edited the answer

Comment: There is no point in this initializer block: the array goes out of scope after the block, so there is no useful side effect from running it. The variable should be declared outside the block.